# How can I set perltidy formating to break lines on chained methods

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

What setting in .perltidyrc will make that chained methods will apear in new line?

Got:

```
$t->post_ok("/foo")->status_is(200)->json_is('/data',"bar");
```

Expected:

```
$t->post_ok("/foo")
  ->status_is(200)
  ->json_is('/data',"bar");
```

Comment: The `-bom` option will *preserve* that style of formatting, but a quick glance through the docs didn't find a way to generate it.

Comment: ... and for me a long look through docs doesn't find anything either

Comment: Thanks guys, then I guess will keep the current formatting to single line.